# BIRT.Question marks instead Cyrillic symbols in parameters in where clause

Tags: birt, maximo

I'm using **BIRT 3.7.1** and **Maximo 7.5**.
I need to get report with data which was sorted in **List** tab in application (f.e. Assets).
I do this using the chekbox "use Where clause" (in Maximo report properties).
I get the string whith where clause using the **params["where"]**. Everything is good except one thing. When I filter data and use cyrillic symbols I get the string like " '%????%' " instead of " '%БЛАБЛА%' " (in BIRT where clause). In logs I noticed that Maximo "understands" these cyrillic symbols, and displays it in a right way but in report context i get " '%????%' ". I tried with reportContest.getHttpServletRequest().getParameter("qbrwhereclase") but I get the string with question marks too. How to get right symbols?
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. In **System properties application** in **Maximo** was missing the **mxe.report.passEncryptedWhere**. When a property has been added, cyrillic symbols become properly passed to birt parameter.